# Grub: no such partition

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub, arch-linux

I have dual boot (windows,arch linux) I've changed something in Windows disk manager and after rebooting and booting up in arch I get the following error: `Grub: no such partition`
I've found a fix for this:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt8)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt8)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

but I have to do this every time I reboot
How can I fix this?

Comment: What distro? You normally run update-grub but you may need to edit an additional file as well.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I use Arch linux, but update-grub doesn't work for me, after I run update-grub it says `command not foud`

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/update_grub_arch_linux/